# Triangle ABC, trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC$ , 
 $\dfrac{a}{\cos(A)}=\dfrac{b}{\cos(B)}=\dfrac{c}{\cos(c)}$, and 
$b =2$. Then, is the area of the $∆ABC$ equal to?

By $\sin$, $\dfrac{a}{\sin(A)}=\dfrac{b}{\sin(B)}=\dfrac{c}{\sin(c)}$
and the area of the triangle will be
$\dfrac{ab\sin{C}}{2}$, but I don't know how do I proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Using done law,

$$\tan A=\tan B=\tan C$$

From the first relationship, $$\dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\cos A\cos B}=0$$

$\implies A-B=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

As $0<A,B,C<\pi$ $A=B$

Similarly we can show $B=C$

So, it's an equilateral triangle

Comment: just an observation: if  $0<A,B<\pi$ and $\tan A =\tan B \rightarrow A=B$

Comment: @Vasya, That's what I have derived